# animate text writing to give the appearance that someone is writing by hand at runtime

Tags: android, animation, libgdx, android-animation

I looking for a way to animate text writing by hand. Lets say I want to write string TEXT. The animation would first write upper, horizontal part of T, than the lower, vertical part, afterwards it would proceede to vertical line in E, and than it would write the 3 horizontal lines and so on. How does one create such animation in libgdx? Actually how does on create such animation in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need the animation for one or two things you could create the animation using an image software. First create the separate images onto a sprite sheet and then use the libgdx [animation class](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/Animation.html) ([wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/2D-Animation)) to run the animation.

This is the probably simplest way if you have a small and few animations.

Hope I helped :)

Comment: Thanks for stopping by. Keyframe animation is always something you can do. I was looking form a more programmable solution

Comment: With some external tools this is easily achieved.